# Tomcat 9 BaseInterceptor jar missing

Tags: java, tomcat, interceptor, tomcat9

I'm trying to create a request Interceptor (using Tomcat 9) based on BaseInterceptor, as suggested in the following link: [BaseInterceptor](http://tomcatbook.sourceforge.net/book/defaulthtml/ch04.html),
but I can't seem to find any reference to the jar file for Tomcat 9. Is this way of implementing interceptors been deprecated and the newer Tomcat versions have another way of doing it?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: A quick google indicates that that was only used in Tomcat 3.

Comment: @tgdavies you should post that as an answer, that's a valid answer

Comment: If you tell us what you want your interceptor to do we can suggest a standard mechanism -- maybe a servlet filter?

Comment: Thanks guys! I see that Tomcat 9 has something called Valve that seems pretty much a Interceptor.. also founf about filters searching for a way to do this. @tgdavies: I'm trying to implement security using JWT, is this a good way of doing it? (I mean using jersey filters)

Comment: My inclination would be to use a Servlet Filter because a) they are part of the standard servlet API, so whatever you do would be portable between containers and b) when you map them in web.xml you can specify a URL pattern, in case you have resources you don't want to apply the filter to.

Comment: If you want to implement JWT, you should join the Tomcat users' mailing list and get some suggestions, there. SO isn't really meant for discussions and designs, while you can get good advice and help on the list.

Comment: @tgdavies thanks!! I'll take a look at it!! Christopher, the post wasn't meant as a discussion, it just evolved into one. I'll take a look at the tomcat mailing list, thanks!